# Postgresql transform column type from jsonb to array type enum

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration

I have column "scopes" which is jsonb type and contains array of strings ["admin","agent"].
I want to transform it to enum array type.
I am using postresql.

This is my migration.

```
CREATE TYPE enum_scopes AS ENUM ( 'owner', 'admin', 'agent', 'user' );

ALTER TABLE public.users ALTER COLUMN scopes TYPE enum_scopes[] USING scopes::text::enum_scopes[];
```

After i run migration i get this: MigrationError: malformed array literal: "["admin"]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first create a helper function like this

```sql
create or replace function jsonb_array_to_array(j jsonb) returns text[] as
$$
  select case 
    when j is null then '{}' 
    else (select array_agg(txt) from jsonb_array_elements_text(j) txt)
  end;
$$ language sql;
```

and then

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.users ALTER COLUMN scopes
  TYPE enum_scopes[] USING jsonb_array_to_array(scopes)::enum_scopes[];
```

The helper function is useful and generic enough to be reused in other cases too.

Comment: I am getting another error MigrationError: column "scopes" contains null values,
Is there a way the column to be epmty array [] insted of null.

Comment: Sure. See updated answer (the function definition).